# Calculating kurtosis from an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have this code:

```
import cv2
from scipy.stats import kurtosis, skew

def main():
    img1 = 'lenna.jpg'
    gray_img = cv2.imread(img1, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    print(f'Kurtosis: {kurtosis(gray_img)}')
```

I want to calculate the kurtosis for an given image, but when I run this code, it shows like this:

[image]

Is it right to return all those values? In my thoughts it supposedly return a single value, because when I run kurtosis in matlab, it returns `1.8561`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `kurtosis` on `axis=0` by default ([see docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html)), but it seems like you're trying to run it on the whole array. So you can try `axis=None`:

```
kurtosis(gray_img, axis=None)
```

**Example**:

```
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(5,5))

>>> im
array([[104, 125,  26, 194,  47],
       [198,  46, 105,  38, 241],
       [211, 115,  62, 196, 169],
       [ 92, 184, 212, 100, 117],
       [212,  35, 208,  52,   3]])

>>> kurtosis(im)
array([-1.78890733, -1.32154862, -1.66900354, -1.74522902, -1.30434102])

>>> kurtosis(im, axis=None)
-1.3968689968948007
```

**[EDIT]**: From your comments, you are trying to calculate skewness, not kurtosis. For this, use:

```
from scipy.stats import kurtosis,skew
skew(gray_img, axis=None)
```

In matlab, on the array above, your code (taken directly from your comments) gives:

```
im =

   104   125    26   194    47
   198    46   105    38   241
   211   115    62   196   169
    92   184   212   100   117
   212    35   208    52     3

>> I2 = im2double(im); 
>> s=skewness(I2(:))

s =

    0.0118
```

In `scipy`, it gives:

```
>>> skew(im,axis=None)
0.011819746815198935
```

**[Edit #2]**: It seems `MATLAB`'s default kurtosis definition is `Pearson's`, whereas `Scipy`'s is `Fisher's`. +1 to `scipy` for being more flexible than `MATLAB`! So you can use:

```
kurtosis(im, None, fisher=False)
```

To get the same results:

```
# Scipy:
>>> kurtosis(im,None, fisher=False)
1.6031310031051993
# Matlab:
>>  s=kurtosis(I2(:))

s =

    1.6031
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting different values from matlab, is there some mistake?

Comment: >> I=imread('lenna.jpg');
>> I2 = im2double(I);
>> s=kurtosis(I2(:);   I'm running like this in matlab

Comment: See my edits, you're trying to get skewness not kurtosis

Comment: See my second edits, it reproduces the same kurtosis as `MATLAB` :) Hope that helps!